# Compare current row timestamp with previous row with condition in function python

Tags: python, function, timestamp

I have a df `sample` with one of the columns named `date_code`, dtype `datetime64[ns]`:

```
date_code
2022-03-28
2022-03-29
2022-03-30
2022-03-31
2022-04-01
2022-04-07
2022-04-07
2022-04-08
2022-04-12
2022-04-12
2022-04-14
2022-04-14
2022-04-15
2022-04-16
2022-04-16
2022-04-17
2022-04-18
2022-04-19
2022-04-20
2022-04-20
2022-04-21
2022-04-22
2022-04-25
2022-04-25
2022-04-26
```

I would like to create a column based on some conditions comparing current row with previous. I trying to create a function like:

```
def start_date(row):
    if (row['date_code'] - row['date_code'].shift(-1)).days >1:
        val = row['date_code'].shift(-1)
    elif row['date_code'] == row['date_code'].shift(-1):
        val = row['date_code']
    else:
        val = np.nan()
    return val
```

But once I apply

```
sample['date_zero_recorded'] = sample.apply(start_date, axis=1)
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

How I should compare current row with previous with condition?

**Edited: expected outoput**

if current row more than previous by 2 or more, get previous

if current row equal past, get current

else, return NaN (incl. if current >1 than previous)

```
date_code   date_zero_recorded
2022-03-28  NaN
2022-03-29  NaN
2022-03-30  NaN
2022-03-31  NaN
2022-04-01  NaN
2022-04-07  2022-04-01
2022-04-07  2022-04-07
2022-04-08  NaN
2022-04-12  2022-04-08
2022-04-12  2022-04-12
2022-04-14  2022-04-12
2022-04-14  2022-04-14
2022-04-15  NaN
2022-04-16  NaN
2022-04-16  2022-04-16
2022-04-17  NaN
2022-04-18  NaN
2022-04-19  NaN
2022-04-20  NaN
2022-04-20  2022-04-20
2022-04-21  NaN
2022-04-22  NaN
2022-04-25  2022-04-22
2022-04-25  2022-04-25
2022-04-26  NaN
```

Comment: Is it correct that if the difference in days (`row['date_code'] - row['date_code'].shift(-1)`) is exactly 1 you set it to`np.nan`? Just to be sure it was not a typo.

Comment: @user2246849 yes, exactly, as the aim is to get first date of continuous period. Since diff=1 is simple next day and it is doesn't breake sequence, I will filter out then those rows.

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `iterrows` and use vectorial code instead.

For example:

```
sample['date_code'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['date_code'])

sample['date_zero_recorded'] = (
 sample['date_code'].shift()
 .where(sample['date_code'].diff().ne('1d'))
)
```

output:

```
    date_code date_zero_recorded
0  2022-03-28                NaT
1  2022-03-29                NaT
2  2022-03-30                NaT
3  2022-03-31                NaT
4  2022-04-01                NaT
5  2022-04-07         2022-04-01
6  2022-04-07         2022-04-07
7  2022-04-08                NaT
8  2022-04-12         2022-04-08
9  2022-04-12         2022-04-12
10 2022-04-14         2022-04-12
11 2022-04-14         2022-04-14
12 2022-04-15                NaT
13 2022-04-16                NaT
14 2022-04-16         2022-04-16
15 2022-04-17                NaT
16 2022-04-18                NaT
17 2022-04-19                NaT
18 2022-04-20                NaT
19 2022-04-20         2022-04-20
20 2022-04-21                NaT
21 2022-04-22                NaT
22 2022-04-25         2022-04-22
23 2022-04-25         2022-04-25
24 2022-04-26                NaT
```

Comment: It miss one additional condition, for example where index=22, `date_zero_recorded` should be as by index=21, because  `2022-04-25` > `2022-04-22` by 3 days, so it should return `2022-04-22`. For those which the same as previous and `else` it works correctly.

Comment: @ker_laeda86 thus my request for you to provide the full expected output as edit in the question ;)

Comment: check the update

Comment: It works great, thanks! Probably I should read more about `.where` to get confident when it should be used instead of `iterrows`

Comment: Note that I could have used `.mask(sample['date_code'].diff().eq('1d'))` with the exact same output ;)

Comment: regarding iteration, the general rule with pandas it to never loop unless you know that you really need to ;)